# Transfer file to server from FTP server

Tags: ftp, file-transfer

I've 2 server:
Server A: Centos, webmin installed, with access to everything, SSH included.

Server B: only FTP access

On Server B I've a file of 10GB and I want to move it to Server A directly, and not downloading it on my PC and then upload it again.

Is it possible? What should I do? PHP or SSH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading the question correctly, you want to get a file from ServerB which you only have FTP access to onto ServerA. Why not download it over FTP to ServerA? Just use `ftp Server-B.com` and `get file.10g.zip` to grab the file from ServerB and download it onto ServerA.

Alternatively, use wget: `wget ftp://serverb/path/to/file.zip`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I'll try this. Is there any way to specify the path in which I want to save the file?

Comment: Both commands save the file in the current folder you're in on the server. With wget, you can use: `wget -O /path/to/destination/ ftp://...`